# I want to retrieve the info that corresponds to that index as a dictionary and without one: sqlite3

Tags: mysql, database, python-3.x, sqlite

I haven't been able to figure out how to return the values as a dictionary, for example, if dic = true it would return
{’idx’: 3, ’name’: ’me’, ’passwd’ ’a9993e364706816aba3e25717850c26c9cd0d89d’}

```
def retrieve(self, idx, dic = True):
    '''
    returns a tuple with the three
    values of the record with index idx, or returns None
    if an exception occurred, if the
    option dict is False. By default,
    dict=True and on return is a dictionary with the
    keys ’idx’, ’name’ and ’passwd’.
    The values in the dictionary correspond to the fields
    in the record with index idx
    '''


    if dic == False:

        query = 'SELECT * FROM players WHERE idx = ?'

        self.cr.execute(query)

    if dic == True:

        query = 'SELECT * FROM players WHERE idx = ?'

        self.cr.execute(query)

    self.db.commit()

    print(self.cr.fetchall())
```

I tried running the function with the idx as a string input and it was able to fetch me the tuple without the dictionary, but I believe this is more of a formatting issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you docstrings are lying, parameter was renamed into `dic`

Comment: instead of `if some_flag == True`/`if some_flag == False` just do `if some_flag`/`if not some_flag`

Comment: also docstrings supposed to be in [triple double quotes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#one-line-docstrings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to make dictionary from tuple, you can store your columns names in some variable and then build dictionary from columns names and your records tuples with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) like

```
def retrieve(self, idx, dic=True):
    query = 'SELECT * FROM players WHERE idx = {idx}'.format(idx=idx)
    self.cr.execute(query)
    self.db.commit()

    records_tuples = self.cr.fetchall()
    if dic:
        columns_names = ['idx', 'name', 'passwd']
        records_dicts = [dict(zip(columns_names, record_tuple))
                         for record_tuple in records_tuples]
        return records_dicts
    else:
        return records_tuples
```

Comment: thank you very much, this was exactly what I was looking for!